# java lang nullpointerexception en android al llamar método

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

Que tal!
Tengo este problema:
Cree un `Asynctask` para enviar datos por php a un servidor en línea, el cual controlo desde un método llamado `servicioo()` en la clase `MainActivity`. Este método debe ser llamado desde un servicio para ser ejecutado por el mismo servicio. el método del AsyncTask es este:

```
public void servicioo() {
    try {
        String datos = Secure.getString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        new CargarDatos().execute("http://www.myestupidaysensualpaginaweb.mx/serviceweb.php?nombre=" + nombre + "&" + "longitud=" + longitud + "&" + "latitud=" + latitud + "&" + "direccion=" + direccion + cityName + "&" + "equipo=" + datos);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception 1: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Aquí está el código del servicio:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servicio iniciado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
         MainActivity t = new MainActivity();
         t.servicioo();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception 2: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

El problema reside es que al llamar al método donde ejecuto el service web (servicioo) manda una excepcion que dice así:

java.lang.NullPointerException

El servicio web lo he ejecutado desde un botón y funciona perfectamente, igual funciona perfectamente el servicio, el problema es del objeto que llama al metodo servicioo ya que le puse en la excepción código de error 2 y da ese codigo de error más el nullpointerexception. Ya sé que es un objeto vacío, que hay que darle parametros, ya investigué y todas las formas posibles que he encontrado no me han dado resultado.

Comment: Esto es demasiado amplio, puedes agregar que mas indica el mensaje, principalmente donde mencione "Caused by". El código del servicio no esta completo y estas llamando MainActivity. Agrega también MainActivity.

Comment: Sólo manda ese mensaje, no manda más detalle. Aquí una captura de pantalla: https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-i2z-HpP7cy4/WdLQBYNhiyI/AAAAAAAAAog/7-bCd4cvnRAuSx6OXyRuS9VH8uM4T_m4gCLcBGAs/s1600/Sin%2Bt%25C3%25ADtulo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se produce al instanciar MainActivity y tratar de llamar un método en una instancia con valor null, en realidad esta no es la forma de instanciar MainActivity ( o alguna clase que extiende de Activity):

```
 MainActivity t = new MainActivity();
 t.servicioo();
```

#### `¿Como instanciar MainActivity?`

Para instanciar MainActivity, agrega los siguientes métodos en MainActivity, un constructor y un método para obtener su instancia:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{ 

    private static MainActivity myself;


    public MainActivity() {
        myself = this;
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return myself;
    }

...
...
```

Ahora de esta forma puedes obtener la instancia y llamar el método sin problema de esta forma:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servicio iniciado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
         //MainActivity t = new MainActivity();
         //t.servicioo();

         //* Obtiene instancia de MainActivity y llama método servicioo().
         MainActivity.getInstance().servicioo();

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception 2: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvió totalmente!

Comment: Excelente Juan! , saludos!